# How to count the number of keys in a map

Tags: java

I have a map with keys as A1, A2, A3, B1, is there a way to find out how many A's I have, it should return me 3.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I have a map populated from a utility which contains access levels. Say A1, A2, A3. sometimes it may have one, two or any. How do I find out how many access levels (A's) are there as keys?

Comment: Java please, we can't compile English.

Comment: Your title is confusing, it should probably read 'specific keys' or else you will get answers with the count of all keys

Comment: Does `A` represent some other data type other than a `String`?

Comment: Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String> ();
  
  dataValuesMap.put("ACCESS1", "1");
  dataValuesMap.put("RECESS1", "2"); I want to count the number of keys starts with ACCESS and in this case, it should give me 3
  dataValuesMap.put("ACCESS2", "3");
  dataValuesMap.put("ACCESS3", "4");

Comment: No, it is a map of String, String

Comment: @AbhijitDeb: Please edit that into your post. Never post segments of code in the comments.

Comment: Whoa, so the keys do _not_ look like `A1`, `A2`, etc.  So would it be correct to say you are looking for _the number of keys in a given map that are strings beginning with `ACCESS` (all capitalized)_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poorly phrased question, but *if* the values you have as keys (A1, A2, etc...) are String and you want to check by the first letter of the key, you can try something like this:

```
    int count = 0;
    for (String k : myMap.keySet()){
        if(k.startsWith("A")){
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This did the trick but is there any better way without looping, like regular expression sort?

Comment: um, why the downvote?

Comment: downvote? did not get it...

Comment: someone downvoted my answer (that you said worked) for an unknown reason. To answer your question, the keys to a Map are a Set. To check what's in them you need to iterate over them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in a method:

```
Map yourMap;
count i=0;
Iterator it = yourMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    if((pairs.getKey()).contains("A")) i++;
}
return i;
```

Edit: I am still unsure if you want to check whether the key contains or starts with "A" but using the following condition instead would work to check if the key starts with "A":

```
if((pairs.getKey()).startsWith("A")) i++;
```

Comment: I would probably keep a counter as items are added to the map so that you don't need to iterate over the whole map to get the answer

Comment: but contains matches exact string so this will not work because I have say A1, A2 and A3

Comment: I do not have control over populating the map, I get it from another system

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your comments. You want an exact match? You could use: `if((pairs.getKey()).equals("A")) i++;` instead.

Comment: I do not want exact match, I need something like sql equivalent of like 'A%'

Comment: Oh I see, then use `if((pairs.getKey()).startsWith("A")) i++;`